# No puedo traer los errores del importador de usuarios de excel laravel

Tags: php, laravel, excel

Hola hace dias me encuentro con el problema de que no logro traer los errores que le surgen al cmusuariosimport trate de diferentes formas como

```
 public function onFailure(Failure ...$failures){}
```

Por ejemplo tengo esto en el cmusuarios que me trae todos los errores si pongo un dd($faiulres) me trae todo pero si traigo ese $failures en el controlador esta vacio. o si traigo directamente toda la funcion onFailure.

```
 foreach ($failures as $failure) {
         $failure->row(); // row that went wrong
         $failure->attribute(); // either heading key (if using heading row concern) or column index
         $failure->errors(); // Actual error messages from Laravel validator
         $failure->values(); // The values of the row that has failed.
     }
```

Pero realmente no encuentro la manera para traer los errores del excel y mostrarlos en la pantalla si alguien me pudiera ayudar seria de mucha ayuda. gracias.

A continuacion expongo mi codigo del CMusuariosImport:

```
{

   // use RemembersRowNumber;gi
   use Importable, SkipsFailures;

   private $numRows;
   private $nombre = [
       "name",
       "email",
       "legajo",
       "empresa",
       "telefono",
       "nro_documento",
       "tipo_documento",
       "fecha_ingreso",
       "status",
       "sucursal",
       "gerencia",
       "fecha_egreso"
   ];

   /**
   * @param array $row
   *
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
   */
   public function __construct($array){
       $this ->  nombre['name'] = $array[0];
       $this ->  nombre['last_name'] = $array[1];
       $this ->  nombre['rol'] = $array[2];
       $this ->  nombre['nro_documento'] = $array[3];
       $this ->  nombre['tipo_documento'] = $array[4];
       $this ->  nombre['email'] = $array[5];
       $this ->  nombre['legajo'] = $array[6];
       $this ->  nombre['telefono'] = $array[7];
       $this ->  nombre['empresa'] = $array[8];
       $this ->  nombre['sucursal'] = $array[9];
       $this ->  nombre['gerencia'] = $array[10];
       $this ->  nombre['fecha_ingreso'] = $array[11];
       $this ->  nombre['status'] = $array[12];
       $this ->  nombre['fecha_egreso'] = $array[13];
   }
   public function model(array $row)
   {
        $empresa = Empresa::where('nombre_fantasia','=', $row[ $this ->  nombre['empresa']])->get();
        $sucursal = Sucursal::where('nombre','=', $row[ $this ->  nombre['sucursal']])->get();
        $gerencia = Gerencia::where('nombre','=', $row[ $this ->  nombre['gerencia']])->get();
        $nombre_rol = Role::where('name','=', $row[ $this ->  nombre['rol']])->get();


          $nro_documento = $row[ $this ->  nombre['nro_documento']];
         $last_name = $row[ $this ->  nombre['last_name']];
         $rest = substr( $nro_documento, -4);
         $password = $last_name . $rest;


       ++$this->numRows;
       $usuario= User::updateOrCreate([
           'name' => $row[ $this ->  nombre['name']],
           'last_name' => $row[ $this ->  nombre['last_name']],
           'email' => $row[ $this ->  nombre['email']],
           'password' => Hash::make($password),
           'nro_documento' => $row[ $this ->  nombre['nro_documento']],
           'tipo_documento' => $row[ $this ->  nombre['tipo_documento']],
           'id_empresa' => $empresa != '[]' ? $empresa[0] -> id : null,
           'legajo' => $row[ $this ->  nombre['legajo']],
           'telefono' =>$row[ $this ->  nombre['telefono']],
           'fecha_ingreso' =>\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[ $this ->  nombre['fecha_ingreso']]),
           'status'=>$row[ $this ->  nombre['status']],
           'id_sucursal'=> $sucursal != '[]' ? $sucursal[0] -> id : null,
           'id_gerencia'=> $gerencia != '[]' ? $gerencia[0] -> id : null,
           'fecha_egreso'=>\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[ $this ->  nombre['fecha_egreso']]),

        ]);
        $role = RoleUser::updateOrCreate([
            'role_id' => $nombre_rol != '[]' ? $nombre_rol[0] -> id : null,
            'user_id' => $usuario->id,
         ]);

   }

   public function rules(): array
   {
       return [

                $this ->  nombre['name'] => 'required|max:20',
                $this ->  nombre['last_name'] => 'required|max:20',
                $this ->  nombre['email']    => 'required|max:50|unique:users,email',
                $this ->  nombre['empresa'   ]=> 'required|max:20',
                $this ->  nombre['tipo_documento'   ]=> 'required|max:5',
                $this ->  nombre['nro_documento'   ]=> 'required|max:20|unique:users,nro_documento',
                $this ->  nombre['legajo']=> 'required|max:10|unique:users,legajo',
                $this ->  nombre['telefono']=> 'required|max:20',
                $this ->  nombre['fecha_ingreso']=> 'nullable',
                $this ->  nombre['status'] => 'max:10',
                $this ->  nombre['sucursal']=> 'max:10',
                $this ->  nombre['gerencia']=> 'max:10',
                $this ->  nombre['fecha_egreso']=> 'nullable',
           ];

   }

   public function batchSize(): int
   {
       return 600;
   }
   public function chunkSize(): int
   {
       return 1000;
   }
```

Y pongo mi controlador en donde trate de consultar el error pero simpre me traer el array vacio donde deberian estar los errores como el failure

```
 public function import(Request $request){

        if(!AuthController::ValidateApiKey($request)){
            return response()->json(['msj'=>'Permiso denegado','err'=>'404'],404);
        };

         $oFile = $request->file('file');
         $aAllowExtension = ['xls', 'csv', 'xlsx'];

         $sFileExtension = $oFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
         if (!in_array($sFileExtension, $aAllowExtension)) {
             return $this->response()->error('El sufijo del archivo que cargó no es compatible, es compatible' . implode(',', $aAllowExtension));
         }
         if ($oFile->getSize() >= 20480000) {
             return $this->response()->error('El archivo que cargó es demasiado grande, el tamaño máximo es 20M');
         }
         $headings = (new HeadingRowImport)->toArray(request()->file('file'));
         $import = new CMusuariosImport($headings[0][0]);
         $array = ( $import )->toArray(request()->file('file'));
         $errores_lista = array();
         $lista_docs = array();

            Excel::queueImport($import, request()->file('file'));

            $codigo = bin2hex(random_bytes(4));

            $data = [
               'usuarios' => $errores_lista,
               'errores' =>  count($errores_lista),
               'subidos' => count($array[0]) - count($errores_lista),
               'total' => count($array[0]),
               'json' => $codigo,

            ];

            file_put_contents(public_path('docs'). $codigo.'.json', json_encode($lista_docs));

            return response()->json($data,200);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No es que te traiga un array vacío, sino que tú declaras uno, y en ningún momento lo llenas con los eventuales errores.

```
  $errores_lista = array();  // se crea como un array vacío

  Excel::queueImport($import, request()->file('file'));

  $data = [
     'usuarios' => $errores_lista, // acá sigue vacío
     'errores' =>  count($errores_lista)
  ];
```

Con respecto a la obtención de los errores, [la documentación indica dos posibles soluciones](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#gathering-all-failures-at-the-end). Primero, atrapando una excepción

```
try {
      Excel::queueImport($import, request()->file('file'));
} catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) {
     $failures = $e->failures();
     foreach($failures as $failure {
        // haces algo con $failure
     }
}
```

Esta alternativa ocurre **en el contexto del controller.**

Segunda alternativa, lo que intentaste usar tú, es implementando la interfaz `SkipsOnFailure`, que específicamente requiere un método

```
public function onFailure(Failure ...$failures)
{
  // haces algo con las $failures
}
```

Que ocurre **en el contexto del importador** y no está pensado para que lo invoques tú, sino que el importador lo usa para manejar los errores *en vez de* tirar una excepción (y por lo mismo es excluyente con la primera alternativa).

¿Qué se supone que debes hacer dentro de ese método? Por suerte eso no necesitas responderlo. Lo que haces es usar el trait `SkipsFailures` (que suena casi igual, pero es un complemento con la interfaz `SkipsOnFailure`), el cual atrapa y disponibiliza los errores en un método `failures`.

Tu importador se vería más o menos como:

```
class CMUsuariosImport implements ToModel, WithChunkReading, WithBatchInserts, SkipsOnFailure
   
   use SkipsFailures;
   
   ... el resto de la clase...

}
```

Y desde el controlador obtendrías los errores como:

```
  Excel::queueImport($import, request()->file('file'));

  $errores_lista = $import->failures(); 

  $data = [
     'usuarios' => $errores_lista, 
     'errores' =>  count($errores_lista)
  ];
```

Comentario al márgen: no es buena idea importar a un array sólo para contar los registros. Mal que mal, ese valor ya lo tienes:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
  ...

  ++$this->numRows; // Acá

}
```

El único detalle es que `$numRows` lo tienes declarado como private, así que tendrás que declarar un getter o declararla como pública. Mejor el getter, para no sobreescribirla sin querer

```
public function numRows() {
   return $this->numRows;
}
```

---

Edit: entendiendo un poco más de tu caso particular (pero lo de arriba sigue aplicando al caso general), como estás usando el trait `SkipsFailures` deberías entender sus consecuencias, porque tu método ahora tiene, además de lo existente;

- un método `onFailure` que sólo se preocupa de ir metiendo las failures a la variable $failures
- una variable privada, `$failures`, que es un array.
- una función pública `failures` que retorna el contenido del array.

Si tu clase está usando ese trait, el hecho de declarar localmente alguno de sus métodos o variables los sobreescribirá. Esto no dará ningún error (por el diseño de las Traits desde PHP 5.4), a menos que la visibilidad sea más restrictiva. En otras palabras:

- si tu importador declara `onFailure`, ese es el que se ejecuta, y no el que está en el trait. Ese `onFailure` donde hoy sí te funciona el `dd`  debe llenar el array $failures en la instancia, o siempre seguirá vacío.

Me suena como que el mejor camino a seguir es quitar el `use SkipsFailures` de tu clase y sólo copiar los métodos del trait, como primer paso. Corres la importación y compruebas si ahora $failures tiene contenido.

Comment: Probe de la siguiente manarea pero igualmente   $import->failures(); me sigue devolviendo el $errores_lista vacia.  Excel::queueImport($import, request()->file('file'));

                $errores_lista = $import->failures();

                $data = [
                   'usuarios' => $errores_lista,
                   'errores' =>  count($errores_lista)
                ];

                return  $data;

Comment: Y te consta que sí hay errores? Porque lo siguiente a intentar es manejar tú mismo el onFailure

Comment: si pongo un dd($faiulures) me tira los errores pero tiene que ser dentro del cmusuarioimport pero si lo hago dentro del controlador vacio me devuelve

Comment: En vez de `dd($failures)` podrías asignar `$failures`  a una variable pública de la instancia. Ej `$this->publicFailures = $failures`  Me imagino que cuando logras ver los errores en el dd evitas el uso del trait `SkipFailures`?

Comment: nosabria donde poner el `$this->publicFailures = $failures ` lo trate de poner en el constructor y me sale demasiados argumentos, tambien en el model

Comment: `public function onFailure(Failure ...$failures){   $this->publicFailures = $failures;
    }` tambien de esta manera pero tampoco logro enviar los errores

Comment: el unico momento en donde veo el dd es cuando la pongo dentro de onFailure 
  `public function onFailure(Failure ...$failures)   {    dd($failures) ;    }` de esta manera claramente se para el proceso y no logro skipear los errores , osea yo se que estan los errores ahi pero no logro mostrarlos en el controlador. si uso SkipFailures